# Matplotlib Formatting X-Axis Shows Jan-1-1970

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

New to Matplotlib, trying to format dates on x axis. If I just use plt.xticks, the date is correct. But if I try to format the values using ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter, it changes my axis values to Jan-1-1970 based. I'm sure this is newbie stuff, thx for the bootstrap. (BTW, running in JupyterLabs notebook).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
%matplotlib inline

# data to plot
#df_plot = df_dts[df_dts.dt>"8/17/2020"]
df_plot = pd.DataFrame({
    'dt': [date(2020,8,19), date(2020,8,20), date(2020,8,21), date(2020,8,22)],
    'open_cnt': [2,15,2,7],
    'close_cnt': [0,2,11,0]
})

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 5, forward=True)
index = np.arange(len(df_plot))
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

rects1 = plt.bar(index, df_plot.open_cnt, bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='orange', label='Open')
rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, df_plot.close_cnt, bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='g', label='Close')

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Workitems')
plt.title('Open & Close Rates')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width/2, df_plot.dt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%d-%y'))
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of messing up with *formatter*, set the index in your *DataFrame*
to proper text representation of your dates and call *plot.bar* on this
object:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax = df_plot.set_index(df_plot.dt.map(lambda s: s.strftime('%b-%d-%y')))\
    .plot.bar(ax=ax, legend=False, title='Open & Close Rates', rot=0,
    color=['orange', 'green'])
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Workitems');
```

For your data I got the following picture:

[image]

As you can see, my code is more concise than yours.

Comment: works perfectly. Didn't know that dataframe index is used as the axis matplotlib.  Is this because it's being called from pandas? Are there other advantages to calling plot from the dataframe itself? And I love how compact your code is, that's awesome.  Thanks @Valdi_Bo ~

Comment: In *pyplot* date formatter works together with a *locator*, specifying for which *x* (date) values print date labels. So here is such a conflict that you have *x* values as **integers** and then you attempted to put *x* labels based on **dates**.

Comment: This doesn't work for regular line plots though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your original code much, you can simply do the transformation when you set the xticks.

```py
df_plot['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df_plot['dt'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width/2, df_plot['dt'].dt.strftime('%b-%d-%y'))
```