# Matplotlib/Seaborn - Plotting datetime objects on the x-axis is giving a very long label

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot time-series data using Seaborn, but the formatting of the x axis tick labels is being very odd, giving me much more detail than I'm interested in. Here is the head of my dataframe, my code, and the output.

Head of Dataframe showing year and month column to be combined:

[image: Head of Dataframe showing year and month column to be combined and made a datetime object]

`df['arrival'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_date_month'] + ' ' + df['arrival_date_year'])`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
count_plot = sns.countplot(x='arrival',data=df,hue='hotel',palette='rocket')

for ind, label in enumerate(count_plot.get_xticklabels()):
    if ind % 3 == 0:  
        label.set_visible(True)
        label.set_rotation(45)
    else:
        label.set_visible(False)

ax.legend(title = 'Type of Hotel')
ax.set_xlabel('Month')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Reservations')
```

[image: Output]

Why are the x axis tick labels being so specific? If I run df['arrival'], I get the following:

[image: this.]

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, all datetime objects are stored as `datetime64[ns]` with precision down to nanoseconds. When you run `df['arrival']`, the output you're getting is what is being displayed but the actual underlying data underneath is at nanosecond precision (and this is what matplotlib is showing on the x-ticks).

I originally suggested using the matplotlib `mdates.DateFormatter` method to fix this, but it's finicky and seems to have trouble interpreting datetimes ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549321/matplotlib-formatting-x-axis-shows-jan-1-1970) brings up a similar issue with the matplotlib dateformatter).

So instead I would suggest converting the `'arrival'` column to a datetime string in your df before creating the sns.countplot:

```
df['arrival'] = df['arrival'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Here is a small example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'hotel': ['Resort Hotel']*10 + ['City Hotel']*10,
    'arrival': list(pd.date_range('2015-07-01','2015-07-10'))*2
})

df['arrival'] = df['arrival'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
count_plot = sns.countplot(x='arrival',data=df,hue='hotel',palette='rocket')

for ind, label in enumerate(count_plot.get_xticklabels()):
    if ind % 3 == 0:  
        label.set_visible(True)
        label.set_rotation(45)
    else:
        label.set_visible(False)

ax.legend(title = 'Type of Hotel')
ax.set_xlabel('Month')
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Reservations')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that but now I'm getting January 1970 as the labels on my x axis. I printed them out and its Jan 1 1970 - Jan 9 1970. I have confirmed that those dates are not in my data. The formatting, however, is correct. The dates were just changed.

Comment: wow that's strange... let me see if i can reproduce the datetime tickmarks you're getting with some sample data of my own. i'll circle back and update my answer when i figure out why that's happening

Comment: @osmanandrew i'm not totally sure why matplotlib dateformatter is having trouble with the datetimes, but my guess would be that sns.countplot is transforming the datetime column into some format that matplotlib is having trouble interpreting (`1970-01-01` is usually the result of an integer being interpreted as a datetime). anyway, hopefully the updated answer works!

Comment: The original data was just given in months and year so is simply adding the two cols together eg. df[month] + df[year] any different than making it a datetime object and then using strftime? I had the arrivals column as a string initially, but I then ran into an issue on the next graph where I use a groupby on arrival and instead of being sorted in chorological order it is sorted in alphabetical (april - sept).


**Update:**

I solved it by using groupby(sort = False). Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @osmanandrew i am generally reluctant to convert datetimes into strings because it changes the meaning of the data (and leads to unintended situations like the sorting issue you described) but i'm glad it ended up working for you! probably not necessary at this point, but you could consider separate columns for a datetime string and a regular string